Polarization 1st Year
Two polarisers are placed at crossed position. At what angle should a third polariser be placed so that the intensity of the emergent light is one-fourth of the intensity of incident light?

It would appear that you're asking, if you have 2 crossed polarizers then at what angle should a third polarizer be, assuming it's placed in between the 2 crossed polarizers, to allow one-fourth the light intensity be transmitted.
If we further assume that that the incident light is "unpolarized" then the angle of the 3rd polarizer should be at 45 degrees relative to the other polarizers.
